# Ignoring line breaks in video URLs

Tags: php, regex, url, youtube

I want to replace YouTube URLs with an iframe. Therefore I am using a regex I copied from different websites that takes video IDs from YouTube URLs.

It doesn't work perfectly. If there is a line break, it doesn't take the entire video ID. Also it doesn't take `&feature=share` from the URL.

**For example:**

Input:

```
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=_NDwn20sMog&u=/watch?v=zl-GC1
6vBm4&feature=share
```

Regex:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/\S*(?:(?:\/e(?:mbed))?\/|attribution_link\?a=.+?watch.+?v(?:%|=)|watch\?(?:\S*?&?v\=))|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,11})/i
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => zl-GC1
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=_NDwn20sMog&u=/watch?v=zl-GC1
)
```

Comment: In order to assist with this matter you will need to provide exactly what you are needing to get from the `regex`

Comment: This may be close: https://regex101.com/r/kP3cG4/1

Comment: Thank you Matt for your reply. I'm sorry my question was not clear. J0e3gan's answer did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify by scrubbing potential whitespace then matching.

Here is an example of what I mean...

```
<?php 

$test = <<<TEST
http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=_NDwn20sMog&u=/watch?v=zl-GC1
6vBm4&feature=share
TEST;

$test = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $test); // NOTE: Scrub potential whitespace.
// NOTE: (&.*)* added to the end of the original pattern to match the
// rest of the query string if any.
preg_match('/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/\S*(?:(?:\/e(?:mbed))?\/|attribution_link\?a=.+?watch.+?v(?:%|=)|watch\?(?:\S*?&?v\=))|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,11})(&.*)*/', $test, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

?>
```

..., which outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(90) "http://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=_NDwn20sMog&u=/watch?v=zl-GC16vBm4&feature=share"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "zl-GC16vBm4"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "&feature=share"
}
```

You can test this approach in an [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/xVTnjP).

Comment: Thank you J0e3gan! scrubbing whitespace and adding (&.*)* to the end of the pattern did the trick.